# Converting &quote; and &#39; into appropriate characters in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on my first project which involves an API.

The API I'm working with gives me strings like:

```
&quot;In our nation&rsquo;s capital, killings have risen by 50 percent.&quot;
```

Is there a way I can simply convert the codes into characters? or do I need to call `gsub` over and over again?

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/htmlentities

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby On Rails you can try below line it display well HTML

```
<%="&quot;In our nation&rsquo;s capital, killings have risen by 50 percent.&quot;".html_safe%>
```

It will output like: **"In our nation’s capital, killings have risen by 50 percent."**